# Chrome/Safari/Edge/Postman Http Header very strange behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, http-headers

The code that responds to a request is the following:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(ex.Detail.HttpStatusCode, ex.Detail.ReasonPhrase);
Response.AddHeader("X-Status", ex.Detail.ReasonPhrase);
```

The funny thing here is that, on the browser/client, when there's a special char involved (such as `ç` or `é`) the reason phrase renders as expected, but the X-Status does NOT!!!

here's a screenshot for the non-believers
[image]

I've tested a uncountable number of encoding combinations but none worked... the X-Status just fails...

I have to use the `X-Status` custom header because Safari overrides whatever message comes with the `StatusText`...

Comment: What do you see when you look at the raw response? The screen show you included looks like the parsed response. Also, you can use something like: HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ex.Detail.ReasonPhrase, Encoding.UTF8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP specification does not define a character encoding for header fields or the status line (well, not beyond US-ASCII). If you need non-ASCII characters, you're on your own. One reliable way is to percent-encode, for instance.

Also note that HTTP/2 doesn't have a status line, thus trying to use that to return information is a non-starter anyway.